# How should I have written this question differently?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-question, asking-questions

I wrote this question earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774132/what-does-this-regular-expression-do-searching-for-a-matching-string-in-string/23774187#23774187.

It immediately received downvotes - that's fine, I still got my question answered. I'm still wondering, however, how else I could have written this question? It's my understanding that SO is for all programmers, not just those that know everything about a language or its concepts and also not just for those who are great researchers (I am not either.)

I was unaware where to search for regular expressions, so I thought SO might be a safe place to ask. Apparently not.

Where else should I have looked before SO / how else should the question have been formatted?

(Also, yes, I helped put the question on hold because I guess it seemed logical.)

Comment: What about consulting the language's API documentation? I'm pretty sure Javadoc has a description of their regular expression syntax. regex isn't magic, to learn them you, well, need to learn them just like you learn the rest of the languages.

Comment: @Mat Fair enough, thanks for your input.

Comment: I'll have the same response as @Mat. You had the magic word to do your research: "Regular Expression", plus maybe after, your language (since the escape characters may have to be "re-escaped"). I don't speak Java, but you even had some methods (`matches`), so you could have looked at the doc. What I think people would have be ok to answers, is that you tried to understand how Regex works, tried a few things, but still get stucked with a unwanted behavior. Looked for it on the web (giving that you tried that, explaining why you thought that it was gonna solve your issue but failed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason for the downvotes is that this question is generally not helpful to anybody else except you right here right now. SO is trying to accumulate generally useful knowledge which will help many people in the future with the same problem. Your question does not fall into that category at all.

> "What does this regular expression do (searching for a matching string in string list)"

If someone was googling or SO-searching (what's the verb here?) for some regex related question and this came up, it doesn't tell anybody anything. What does *what* do? The only way to find out what you're talking about and whether it may be helpful is to click through and read the entire post.

Next, there's a bunch of code in the question, but only a tiny snippet of regexen. It's unclear at first blush whether one needs to read all that code to figure out your question about regexen or whether it's mostly irrelevant.

> I wondering, what exactly does that regex for the matches boolean do?

Now we are wondering what exactly you do and don't understand. Do we have to answer with a broad swing how regexen work in general, or do you only have problems understanding the repeated use of backslashes in the regex?

> Where can I learn to understand regexes better?

SO does categorically not recommend learning material, it's off-topic. It's also not clear whether you've tried to google, tried reading a book, or have made any effort at all to inform yourself about regexen. There's a ton of material out there, you're not the first to want to learn about regexen. SO is not a personalised signpost to tutorials.

As for how you *could* have written the question... first figure out the kernel of the problem, what exactly you are having a problem with. What precisely do you not understand about the code? Have you RTFM for the specific methods which are being called and have understood what they do? Have you looked up the bare basics of regex syntax to get the gist of it? Then maybe at the end of that process you could have come up with a question such as:

> ### What is the significance of repeated use of backslashes in a regex?
>
> I'm having trouble understanding the repetition of backslashes in this code:
>
> ```
>     boolean matches = perm.matches(p
>                     .replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\.")
>                     .replaceAll("\\*", "\\.\\*")
>                     .replaceAll("#", "\\.")
> ```
>
> I think a double backslash in a string literal represents a single backslash in the regex, is that correct? That would mean that blah blah blah... But then I'm confused as to why it's replacing a single backslash with a blah blah blah...

Something along those lines. Clearly stating what you do understand and what you do not, focusing on one specific issue, with a title which may attract and help future visitors.

Comment: Great information. I apologize for my ignorance of how SO works. Thank you, I will apply this in the future.